# Pyspark ML CrossValidator evaluate several evaluators

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, cross-validation

In Sklearn in the GridSearchCV we can give the model different scorings and with the refit param we refit one of them using the best found parameters in on the whole dataset.

Is there any way to do something similar with CrossValidator from the ML package from pyspark?

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-tuning.html#cross-validation), that happens automatically within the `fit()` method of `CrossValidator`:

> After identifying the best ParamMap, CrossValidator finally re-fits the Estimator using the best ParamMap and the entire dataset.

And indeed you can see that that happens in the code [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v3.2.0/python/pyspark/ml/tuning.py#L701), for example:

```
        bestModel = est.fit(dataset, epm[bestIndex])
```